# Error sintaxis mysql al insertar registro

Tags: php

Tengo un problema de inserción de datos,

Este es mi Codigo

```
<?php

if ($_POST['MM_insert']) {

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre_alumno'];
    $sa = $_POST['sexo'];
    $dt = $_POST['documento_tipo'];
    $nd = $_POST['num_documento'];
    $fr = $_POST['Fecha_Registro'] = date('Y-m-d');
    $cea = $_POST['correo_electronico'];
    $da = $_POST['direccion_alumno'];
    $ta = $_POST['telefono_alumno'];
    $ta2 = $_POST['telefono_alumno2'];
    $ma = $_POST['movil_alumno'];
    $rt = $_POST['responsable_tipo'];
    $rt2 = $_POST['responsable_tipo2'];
    $nr = $_POST['nombre_responsable'];
    $nr2 = $_POST['nombre_responsable2'];
    $cr = $_POST['cedula_responsable'];
    $cr2 = $_POST['cedula_responsable2'];
    $mr = $_POST['movil_responsable'];
    $mr2 = $_POST['movil_responsable2'];
    $cer = $_POST['correo_electronico_resp'];
    $cer2 = $_POST['correo_electronico_resp2'];
    $cm = $_POST['comentario'];
    $mes = $_POST['mes'];
    $dia = $_POST['dia'];
    $ano = $_POST['ano'];
    $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
    $aula = $_POST['aula'];
    $idpago = $_POST['id_pago'];
    $pago_nomb = $_POST['plan_nombre'];
    $edad = $_POST['edad_alumno'];
    $creducida = $_POST['creducida'];
    $inscr = $_POST['inscripcion'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $nivel = '4';
    $tcliente = 'Alumno';

    $q = "INSERT into alumno ( nombre_alumno, sexo_alumno, documento_tipo, num_documento, Fecha_Registro, correo_electronico, direccion_alumno, telefono_alumno,telefono_alumno2, movil_alumno, responsable_tipo,responsable_tipo2, nombre_responsable, nombre_responsable2, cedula_responsable,cedula_responsable2, movil_responsable, movil_responsable2, correo_electronico_resp,correo_electronico_responsable2, comentario,mes, dia, ano, grupo, aula, id_pago, plan_nombre, edad_alumno, creducida,inscripcion, password, nivel,tipo_cliente) VALUES ('$nombre', '$sa', '$dt','$nd','$fr', '$cea', '$da', '$ta','$ta2','$ma', '$rt',$rt2','$nr','$nr2','$cr','$cr2','$mr', '$mr2','$cer','$cer2', '$cm','$mes','$dia','$ano','$grupo','$aula','$idpago','$pago_nomb','$edad','$creducida','$inscr','$password','$nivel','$tcliente')";
    $r = $conexion - > query($q) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

}

?>
```

Me lanza el siguiente error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','aaaaaa','cccccc','1234567890','0987654321','1234567890', '0987654321','aaa@em' at line 1
```

Pero entiendo que todo este correcto, alguna sugerencia?
Gracias

Comment: `'$rt',$rt2',` aquí no abriste correctamente las comillas `'$rt','$rt2',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problema**

El error que tienes en tu codigo, se presenta en la **linea 40**:

En la consulta:

```
'$rt',$rt2','$nr'
```

Estas dejando abiertas las comillas. Lo que da paso a un error, ya que el MySQL interpretara la consulta y alli encontrara que falta una comilla, lo que evitara que se inserten los otros datos.

**Posible Solucion**

Lo podrias solucionar haciendo algo como esto:

```
'$rt', '$rt2','$nr'
```

*Agregando las comillas en donde faltan.*
***Pero esto no significa una solucion muy optima para el problema.***

---

Lo que **podrias** hacer, para **simplificar** mas tu codigo, es usar la funcion [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php) de PHP.

**Como funciona?**

De acuerdo a la [documentacion](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php#refsect1-function.sprintf-description) de PHP:

> Devuelve un string producido según el string de formateo dado por format.

**Como podria usarla?**

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
$dato   = "Hola";
$numero = 40;

$q = sprintf("INSERT INTO tabla (dato, numero) VALUES ('%s', %d)", $dato, $numero);
```

Lo que hace [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php) es buscar cada uno de los *comodines* y **reemplazarlos** por un valor, que posteriormente sera agregado en los parametros de la funcion.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @ivan Botero

Comment: @AlexanderQuiroz Con mucho gusto, no olvides darle un vistazo a la funcion sprintf() o incluso al tema de los prepared statements de PHP, eso puede ayudarte a mejorar la seguridad de tu sitio, en cuanto a consultas de SQL se refiere.